# Creating a Reader that can have writes scanned using a Scanner

Tags: go

I apologise for the overly simplistic question but I am trying to wrap my head around `io.Reader` and how to manipulate it.

I am trying to generate a series of events (containing strings) emitted from an event subject.

The event subject I am calling an `Emitter` and I am hoping to be able to arbitrarily write strings to it, where anything scanning will pick up on the events.

I am expecting the events to be lost if there isn't a listener.

```golang
func main() {
    // What should newEmitter look like?
    data := newEmitter()

    go func() {
        for {
            data.WriteString("foobar")
            time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
        }
    }()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(data)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
    }
}
```

Can I get a little help on what my Emitter struct should look like?

I am trying to make it look like an `io.Reader` for the scanner to pick up events.

Answer (score -1):

You need to implement [`io.Reader`](https://tour.golang.org/methods/21) interface, and I guess you also need [`io.Writer`](https://yourbasic.org/golang/io-writer-interface-explained/) for writing to emitter.